# jQuery: disable click during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, click, unbind

So I am making a little quiz, with a I want to disable the click for everything inside `#qWrap` while the animation is operating, thus preventing spamming clicks.
I tried to use `.is(':animated')` but to no effect. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="qWrap">
    <ul id="qBox">
        <!--Q1-->
        <li id="q1" class="qContainer">
            <ul class="qAnswers">
                <li class="qQuestion">
                    <h3>What are italics?</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#q2" class="mums">
                        <h3>Slanted cut of a type</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#q2" class="such">
                        <h3>A group of italian-designed typefaces</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#q2" class="usch">
                        <h3>An other word for the !-sign</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!--Q2-->
        <li id="q2" class="qContainer">
            <ul class="qAnswers">
                <li class="qQuestion">
                    <h3>Who designed Comic Sans?</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#q3" class="usch">
                        <h3>Mathew Carter</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#q3" class="usch">
                        <h3>David Carson</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#q3" class="mums">
                        <h3>Vincent Connare</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!--Q3-->
        <li id="q3" class="qContainer">
            <ul class="qAnswers">
                <li class="qQuestion">
                    <h3>What does Helvetica mean?</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#q4" class="usch">
                        <h3>From Austria</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#q4" class="usch">
                        <h3>From Germany</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#q4" class="mums">
                        <h3>From Switzerland</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.qAnswers li a').bind('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('.qAnswers').find("li:not(.selected, .qQuestion)").delay(200).addClass('notSelected');
    var $anchor = $(this);

    //preventing click within #qWrap 
    if ($('#qWrap').is(':animated')) {
        $('#qWrap').unbind('click');
    }

    //firing the animation
    $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).delay(800).animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
    }, 2000, function() {
        nextCount();
    });
    stopTimer();
    addData();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide us a jsfiddle link of this so we can test?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aHPfc/7/
I didn't get it working perfectly though :P

Answer (score 4):

Your JS code should look like this:

```
$('.qAnswers li a').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //preventing click within #qWrap 
    if ($('#qWrap').is(':animated')) {
        return;
    }

    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('.qAnswers').find("li:not(.selected, .qQuestion)").delay(200).addClass('notSelected');
    var $anchor = $(this);


    //firing the animation
    $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).delay(800).animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
    }, 2000, function() {
        nextCount();
    });
    stopTimer();
    addData();
});
```

The code `$('#qWrap').is(':animated')` is not an event that will trigger when the element is animating, it's a normal check. I moved your `event.preventDefault();` to the top also; figured you want to do that regardless. You might need to move around some other things also.

Comment: Well thanks for the clean-up, didn't really solve my problem though

Comment: @CarlPapworth Ok. Try to [add breakpoints in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints) to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[where you click]').click(
function(){
    if(!$('[what animates]').is(':animated')){
        $('[what animates]').[your_animation];
    }
});
```